# Parameter of type any[] accepts non-array value

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function with a parameter of type `any[]`

```
someFunction(args: any[]): boolean {
  // some code
}
```

Now I want to call the function and pass an array with values of any kind. This should be ok, and it is:

```
someFunction([value1, value2, value3]); // OK, as expected
```

But, if I pass a value which isn't an array, I expect to get a type error, but I don't:

```
someFunction(value1); // OK, but shouldn't I get a type error?
```

Can someone explain why this won't throw an error at compile time?

Comment: What is the type of `value1`?

Comment: Not answering precisely your case, but as a remark : it is valid javascript, as at the end arrays are just a kind of object. Depending on your TS compiler / transpiler  option, any valid Javascript *can* be valid Typescript.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Can be of any kind, let's say `string`, `number`, `Object` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the type of `value1` is `any` then this is valid since `any` is compatible with any other type, so it will be compatible with `any[]`.

So for example you will get an error if you pass a number to the function but not if you pass any

```
function someFunction(args: any[]): boolean {
  return true
}
declare var value1: any;
someFunction(value1) //ok
someFunction(1) //not ok
declare var nonAny: number;
someFunction(nonAny) //not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for Array of type any is:

```
someFunction(args: Array<any>): boolean {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: `any[]` and `Array<any>` are equivalent

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok they are just different ways to say the same thing, they will not have different behaviors